# Problem with accents while "fetching" some data

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch, es6-promise

I'm with a problem with accented words on a 'fetch'... I've tried so many things but nothing changed. Do you folks know how make this out?

The problem is, the accented words come in this value.label variable. I've tried putting the charset on the header, but nothing. The interesting thing is that the values are showed correctly on the request preview in the chrome's dev console.

This is the code I'm using:

```
fetch(url + params, {
    method: "get"
})
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(options => {
    log(options.values());
    options.forEach(value => {
    self.append(`<option value="${value.valor}" >${value.label}</option>`);
    });
});
```

This is the response from the webserver:

```
[{"label":"Sassarica Sapatilhas ","value":492}, 
{"label":"Sassarica Sapatilhas - Av Paulista","value":1547}, 
{"label":"Sassarica Sapatilhas - São Carlos","value":505}]
```

This is what i'm getting in the page:

```
Sassarica Sapatilhas - S�o Carlos
```

And this is the link for the CodePen: 
https://codepen.io/fabioamorim/pen/MZOByK

Comment: the good thing is that we know for certain that your json response is utf-8 ( because it's json, cannot be anything else). so, what's the charset of your page? what your browser says about that?

Comment: @Federkun, my page is UTF-8 too, as my browser says: `document.characterSet
"UTF-8"`

Comment: Plus, I've tested the code with jQuery ajax, and everything goes fine. What's the problem with `fetch`?

Comment: what's the output if you do `${encodeURIComponent(value.label)}`? any chance this is a live page that we can see?

Comment: I'll try to put it live in a codepen or something, just a moment.

Comment: I've added the link for the project.

Comment: Cool. The return content type of `listmenu_item.asp` is `text/html; Charset=iso-8859-1`. It should be utf-8 instead. So, on the server side, change it to utf-8, of change the charset of the page to wait for iso-8859-1 text. Just keep it consistent.

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to the backend... And change the meta of my page does nothing :/

Comment: @Federkun , I've achieved some success by not using the `Body.json()` method. Using the `Body.arrayBuffer()` method, then making a `new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1")` and finally using the `JSON.parse(decoder.decode(arrayBuffer)`....

Comment: This means the `Body.json()` method can't handle very well this kind of _charset_ crusade hahaha